# How to get infinite loop in java to work?

Tags: java, optimization, while-loop, infinite-loop

Here is my code in java.

```
        CameraFrame cf = new CameraFrame();
        while (true) {
            // System.out.println("hello");
            if(cf.cp.play) {
                AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new Game("Snake"));
                app.setDisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, false);
                app.setTargetFrameRate(FPS);
                app.setShowFPS(false);
                app.start();
            }
        }
```

This never runs in java for some reason. I did read somewhere that programming languages like Java and C# optimize the code by not executing such loops (which supposedly serve no purpose). However I have code from (slick2d game library), which never runs here. However if I put a `System.out.println` statement, everything is fine.

So my question is, how do I induce this while loop to run without having to use `System.out.println` line.

Note: I fully understand that infinite loops are bad, but there maybe instances like in a game or in a server, where infinite loops are probably the only best way to go.

Edit:

I have updated the code. CameraFrame is basically another thread which opens a video and displays it on a JFrame, and cf.cp is a JPanel and cf.cp.play is a boolean, triggered by a JButton on the CameraFrame. So I have a JFrame, which has a JButton which should be able to trigger this new window from slick2d.

Comment: You can do that in Java. I think you may have other code that is preventing it from executing. Care to share more of it?

Comment: Try a Thread.Sleep i.e. pause in the loop?

Comment: what makes you think it's not running?

Comment: works for me mate

Comment: @matt The other code is I guess completely irrelevant to the question here, I could post it, but it would only confuse the readers of this question. I mean everything works fine, if I just put a print statement. Same thing happened to me few days ago in Unity C#, when I tried an infinite loop which only worked with a Debug.Log statement.

Comment: Don't assume it's irrelevant. The code you posted doesn't have the stated problem. If you want any help, we'll need more context.

Comment: Ok let me update the question. I think I maybe wrong about the part that the other code maybe irrelevant.

Comment: What's your proof the loop isn't running?

Comment: It will work  as its common to have infinite loop as polling thread in enterprise applications.

Comment: @shmosel The part in the while loop should print out messages to the console and then open a new lwjgl window, both of which never happen. Also Thread.sleep did the trick. So I still think this is something related to how java stops infinite loops or maybe this is somehow related to buffering issues that we see in linux pipes, like when the output doesn't get flushed out until we use fflush or something right?

Comment: Infinite loops without a `sleep` is very very bad, since it may hog all the processing power for itself and may not allow other threads to run. This is really not good scenario for any kind of program, specially a game where could be multiple threads. Most probably `cf.cp.play` is false. As stated by @shmosel below.

Comment: Your loop does nothing because `cf.cp.play` is false. If you want your thread to see it change, it has to be `volatile`.

Comment: Also when people say, it's working, what kind of code are you guys putting inside the while loop to know that it's working?

Comment: We don't need to test it; it's obvious. Loops don't randomly fail to execute.

Comment: a simple main with an endless loop does not terminate.  As @shmosel suggests, your cpu intensive loop will not see the value of `cf.cp.play` change unless it is `volatile`

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I think I now understand why my code doesn't work. Thanks shmosel for pointing things out about volatile(never knew about this keyword in Java) and thanks everyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you're waiting for some other thread to make cf.cp.play become true. The classic way to do this without monopolizing a processor, is to put the thread to sleep, unless you have control over the way the change is done (the other thread), in which case you would be better off doing a notify on something when the value of cf.cp.play becomes true.